# Activerecord: how to query using find_by_sql and include with a variable

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I am trying to query from 3 tables using find_by_sql by activerecords

```
date = '2014-12-14'
bills_with_sms = ActualBill.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM users u LEFT JOIN bills b ON u.id=b.user_id LEFT JOIN actual_bills ab ON b.id= ab.bill_id WHERE u.total_sms_count > 0 AND b.want_sms= true AND  date = ANY (ab.sms_reminder_schedule) AND ab.paid = false AND b.active = true")
```

however when running this code, it will show this error message

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "date" does not exist
LINE 1: ...E u.total_sms_count > 0 AND b.want_sms= true AND  date = ANY...
```

I tried debugging using rails console, and it will give the correct query if I change date to "2014-12-14", so the code will be

```
bills_with_sms = ActualBill.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM users u LEFT JOIN bills b ON u.id=b.user_id LEFT JOIN actual_bills ab ON b.id= ab.bill_id WHERE u.total_sms_count > 0 AND b.want_sms= true AND  '2014-12-14' = ANY (ab.sms_reminder_schedule) AND ab.paid = false AND b.active = true")
```

can someone tell me what is the correct way to query from an array? sms_reminder_schedule is an array of strings. I want to look for bills where an sms is scheduled for that day.

thanks

Comment: Use string interpolation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM users u LEFT JOIN bills b ON u.id=b.user_id LEFT JOIN actual_bills ab ON b.id= ab.bill_id WHERE u.total_sms_count > 0 AND b.want_sms= true AND '#{date}' = ANY (ab.sms_reminder_schedule) AND ab.paid = false AND b.active = true
```

What's going on here is that PG can't find the column date, which I presume that date is the expression you are trying to match with the `ANY` comparison defined in the variable `date`

You'd use string interpolation for this like Marek suggested eg `#{var}`

Comment: thanks, I just need to add apostrophe and it works, 

'#{date}'